# Android handling and creation of touch Events

Tags: android, event-handling, message-queue, touch-event, looper

i'm trying to figure out how exactly touch events work on android.
i know the UI theard manages a Looper that receives touch event Messages through a message queue.
but from there on i cant seem to find any documentation.
anyone know of any documentation ( or even the flow ) regarding how the touch messages arrive to the queue, or what happens with them after they are dequeued (how MotionEvent's are created?)?
10x.

Comment: Are u looking for the flow from device drivers to message queue or from message queue to applications?

Comment: actually i need both, but either one will be more then welcome

Comment: for driver to event queue, you can start looking from EventHub.cpp. It opens and polls the linux Event Devices. EventHub::getEvents is the function to start from. In android source code you can find the files at frameworks/base/services/input/. These files form the libinput.so  which handles the input devices.